# How to implement dependant drop down in a Django model formset

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to figure out how to create a dependant drop down for a model formset, but all I can find is info on drop downs for forms. My models are:

Office, Staff, and Calls

Staff has a foreign key linking it to an Office, and Call has a foreign key linking it to Staff. Calls are created via csv upload, after which a user will manually select the correct staff from a drop down. However, I need this drop down to show only Staff linked to the correct Office.

I've looked at a the formset docs and a number of tutorials but am coming up short on info specific to this problem; any advice on how to approach this? Would like to avoid any JS if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this isn't possible to do server-side, you'll have to use some JS and Ajax.

[Here's](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html) a nice blog post explaining how to implement this. There's also numerous questions/answers on here that may help you: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43939201/dynamically-update-django-form-field-options-using-ajax-to-get-new-queryset), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465711/how-do-i-post-with-jquery-ajax-in-django), and [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518033/django-ajax-how-to-filter-and-display-result-based-on-selection), etc.